# in bash can I force a `cd src` everytime I cd into a go directory?

Tags: bash, cd

I never use my bin or pkg golang dirs. So when I do this:

`cd go`
i'd rather BASH assume I mean
`cd go/src`

how can I tell bash do this everytime?

Comment: Write an alias `cdgo` to mean `cd /home/you/go/src`.

Comment: This question is about bash, belongs on SuperUser and is just a terrible idea in general. You wan to alias cd because you're to lazy to type two more keystrokes to finish the path?

Comment: that's like telling a race car driver, you wanna shave 200 milliseconds off your time for each lap? You're just a lazy race car driver.

Comment: @Pillar: That's not a comment, it's an answer  - and a good one!

Comment: Pillar's answer is not good. I'd have to remember to type a whole new thing. I want to just do a normal cd and have it auto-matically read my brain and put me where I wanna be.

Comment: Well, I, too, actually against such "micro-optimizations". But I'd say that supposedly Andrew is hardly a seasnoed developer yet, and he'll certainly develop a more down-to-Earth perspective to such things ;-) As of now he's supposedly learned a bit on how shell works so why not after all? ;-)

Comment: years and years of cd'ing into java com dot blah dot this dot that has ruined me I guess. I long someday to be a seasnoed developer.

Comment: What I don't understand is what good cd'ing into `src/` will do? I've been writing Go for about as long as anyone, and I've never has occasion to cd directly into the GOPATH src directory. Seems like just setting [CDPATH](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bourne-Shell-Variables) would be much more useful, and not break any builtin functionality.

Comment: i use vim. so I like being in src to type vim foo.go

Comment: There should not be any .go files in your GOPATH/src directory.

Comment: there are not. but there might be a directory will a file called foo.go in a directory called bar, so the full thing I type is vim bar/foo.go from src.  then I might type vim kangaroo/something.go next, also from src.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put

```
function cd()
{
    test $# -eq 0 && return 0
    if [ `basename $1` == "go" ]; then
        builtin cd "$1/src"
    else
        builtin cd "$@"
    fi
}
```

in your `~/.bashrc`.

Note that you won't be able to use command-line options when `cd`-ing into your Go directory because ideally we'd process only the last argument passed to `cd` but you can't easily do this in a POSIX shell (and `bash`).

Comment: nice! this works perfect!